# DigiSpark External Oscillator

Tags: oscillator-clock, digispark

I am trying to set up a PJON SoftwareBitBang network with a bunch of DigiSparks. My setup works well with any other Arduino devices except the DigiSparks. Based on some internet searching I came to the conclusion that it's because DigiSpark doesn't have a built in oscillator.

I bough a bunch of 16Mhz Crystal Oscillators hoping the internet will help me set them up but I couldn't find any resources on how to do that

Does anyone know any resources on how to use an external oscillator on DigiSpark?
Alternatively, can anyone think of any other reason why SoftwareBitBank goesn't work with Digisparks?

Thanks,
Andi

Comment: Is "SoftwareBitBang" a library? I see no reason why bit banging shouldn't work and I think the problem probably is a different layer

Comment: [SoftwareBigBang](https://github.com/gioblu/PJON/tree/master/src/strategies/SoftwareBitBang#compatibility) does support Attiny85/DigiSpark. It is also possible to add external xtal to [Attiny85](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf) with the trade-off of losing two precocious GPIO pins, but you can't just add the external crystal without modifying the firmware of DigiSparks. I think you should focus on why SoftwareBitBang doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, did you installed the DigistumpArduino core to your Arduino IDE which defines the pin 1 and 2 that the SoftwareBigBang is looking for to communicate with Attiny85/DigiSpark.